# Is it possible to run java application on android through openjdk

Tags: android, arm, java

Disambiguation first: question is not about developing or compiling with openjdk code that would be run on dalvik in production. It is about using oracle runtime on android environment.

I'm using java for running small desktop utility application. I have no experience in Android and iOS development and I'm curious to which extent my classic java skills may be transferred to the mobile field.

I've googled couple of methods for running java application on iOS embedding runtime inside the application package. Android has its own partially incompatible and slow java virtual machine. It still is better than nothing, but I'm curious if it is possible to run application on genuine hotspot(openjdk) virtual machine. Android as well as iOS have the ability to run native code. May this ability be exploited to use third-party (non dalvik) jre on android?

I'm not interested on google play market so restrictions from it, if there are any, may not be taken into account.

Rooting is also possible since I'm going to write tools for myself. I would prefer methods that would be easy for installing. Like putting some package files and editing couple of options. And not build my own android distribution like CyanogenMod.

Comment: jainja supports Android and is based on Avian, it's possible to use it with OpenJDK: http://jainja.thenesis.org " the supported platforms are Linux, Windows, xBSD, Minix, Haiku, HelenOS, Java SE, Java ME, Android, Javascript (GWT), Dart, NaCl"

Comment: I had a feeling that soon enough the question becomes outdated

Comment: Google will base its Java language library on OpenJDK but it doesn't mean that it will support exactly the same public APIs than OpenJDK in mobile and desktop environments.

Answer (score 0):

Without rooting the device, I don't think there is a way to do it.

Comment: rooting is not a problem. There is no point in using proprietary device that stoles your freedom.

Comment: No, rooting is not required.  Any standard Android application process would still have a DVM in it, but there's no reason it can't also have a ported/custom JVM implemented in either native code... or in Java compiled to Dalvik.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, see http://openjdk.java.net/projects/mobile/android.html

The instructions are slightly out of date, I managed to do some hacking and get it to build though. Not sure if it runs yet

Comment: _The Zero interpreter used in our Android arm port requires a third party library for calling native functions_ - what a pity. Generic ARM JDK could already use JIT but Android version is still on the Zero.